# javascript document.body undefined if not preceded by a document.write

Tags: javascript

With this minimal webpage:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='test.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

This minmal 'test.js' script fails:

```
document.body.innerText = 'testje';
```

The document.body seems to be undefined:

```
0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'innerText' 
of undefined or null reference
```

If one adds a document.write('blabla') before the code line, it works:

```
document.write('blabla');
document.body.innerText = 'testje';
```

This puzzles me, although it seems rather basic.

I am a Javascript newbe, so some explanation would be most welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't access body element until it's declared and your script is running in `<head>`.

Try this: `window.onload = function(){ document.body.innerText = 'testje'; };`

or place your script below `<body>`

Comment: Hi andrea.r, this is how I ended up fixing it.

Answer (score 5):

At the time the script is running there is no body tag, it hasn't been outputted to the DOM yet.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Place content here -->
    <script type='text/javascript' src='test.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

when using `document.write`, the document is synchronously updated with the new content, and the browser fixes your mistake and adds a body element, that's why it's available after `document.write`.

Answer (score 4):

The script appears in the `head`. At the time it runs, the start of the `body` has not been encountered, so the `body` does not exist and cannot be accessed via the DOM.

`document.write` writes HTML to the document. In this case, character data is being written. Since character data is not allowed in the `head` and the end tag for `head` and the start tag for `body` are optional, this ends the `head` element and starts the `body`. At this point the `body` exists and can be accessed.

Comment: Thanks Quentin. Very knowledgeable!