# javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined

Tags: java, web-services

I got this error will i run the below java file.

```
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.List;

import javax.script.Bindings;
import javax.script.Invocable;
import javax.script.ScriptContext;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class TestForTheThread {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("javascript");
        try {
             URL yahoo = new URL("http://localhost/XMLLoadProject/thiru.js");  
                URLConnection yc = yahoo.openConnection();  
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
                engine.eval(in);
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("fail to load");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("fail to load");
        }
        Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
        Object result;
        try {
            result = invocable.invokeFunction("idplogurl", "thriu");
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

sample js file

```
var idplogurl = function(idpcode) {
    /*! jQuery v1.11.2 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */
   document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+ idpcode+ '"></script>');
}
```

In the javascript file ('thiru.js') contains the document (javascript default object).
some sites say's the not possible with out browser.
**Any one please take a challenge regarding to this error.** 
I got this error

javax.script.ScriptException: sun.org.mozilla.javascript.internal.EcmaError: ReferenceError: "document" is not defined. (#17) in  at line number 17

Please help me any one....

Comment: Also make sure the method "idplogurl" exists

Comment: My java script code.
var idplogurl = function(idpcode) {
    /*! jQuery v1.11.2 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */
   document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+ idpcode+ '"></script>');
}

Answer (score 0):

Try using this or camel case

```
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
 or
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("javaScript");
```

Paste your javascript code

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665509/javascript-document-body-undefined-if-not-preceded-by-a-document-write) you may get some idea.

Comment: I am using these 2 lines
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = mgr.getEngineByName("javascript");
java script file is too long file.
i am trying with the java i got this problem

I tested this in html page working fine

Comment: var idplogurl = function(idpcode) {
    /*! jQuery v1.11.2 | (c) 2005, 2014 jQuery Foundation, Inc. | jquery.org/license */
   document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="'+ idpcode+ '"></script>');
}

Comment: But i call the js file inside the .java file. How can i ?
please give me some more information

Comment: May be that's the reason you are not getting control over there,wait let me search for that

Comment: but why you need document.write there? instead can't you use document.body or innerHTML

Comment: Error is "document" is not defined