# usual text replace dont work in javascript / js

Tags: javascript, html, text, replace

I have like this:

`<body>Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet <br> adipisci velit</body>`

I know it is not compatible with usually html standard.
I have try all of the text replace standard including using jquery too but none is work.
I can replace the text if there is no br tag on that
but if there is br tag i cannot replace any text.
Please dont force me use another tag like div or span or anything.
the 'case' cant be changed and I want to replace the text with javascript/js code
anyone have solution?

Comment: I don't understand the context. `document.body.innerText = 'New text'` (vanilla) or `$('body').text('New text')` (jQuery) should work just fine.

Comment: i am sorry but i just want replace one word not change all words in body tag

Comment: Then you have to iterate over all child elements of the body and replace their contents as necessary.

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452340/iterating-through-each-text-element-in-a-page - but instead of wrapping letters in span tags you would do your text replacement.

Comment: but size of text about 1 megabytes and quite a lot of br tag and about 20 percent of all text have to be changed/replaced......is that possible? can you predict time to finish in browser?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I'm going to throw you a bone here with some fair warnings.

- You didn't post code, hence many down-votes (none from me).
- You didn't select anything on the page, not even an `id` via JavaScript.
- You're going to have to work on refining *how* you target code to be much more specific for this to be useful.
- The code below finds all instances of '22' and replaces them with '33'.

. Stackoverflow bug fix.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function replace_all(s,f,r) {return s.split(f).join(r);}
window.onload = function(event)
{
 var b = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
 b.textContent = replace_all(b.textContent,'22','33');
}
//]]>
</script>
</head>

<body>

122122111

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remember, you're going to have to refine your understanding of JavaScript events, calling functions and how to use JavaScript to target/select parts of the DOM (or page). Read and research before asking questions and it will help smooth your experience next time you ask questions. Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Possible duplicate of [javascript document.body undefined if not preceded by a document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665509/javascript-document-body-undefined-if-not-preceded-by-a-document-write)

I havent really seen any example code so i cant really explain what youve done wrong. But document.body should work fine?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet <br> adipisci velit
<script>
    window.onload = function(){ document.body.innerText = 'testje'; };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry but i just want replace one word not change all words in body tag...... as i said i can change one word if there is not br tag but if there is br tag ,i can't....

Comment: As cherryDT said you have to iterate over all child elements of the body and replace their contents as necessary.