# Why is document.body not working on my subpages?

Tags: javascript, html

**Background**
I've created a simple workaround to get a fixed background to work on iPad and iPhone devices, i.e creating an empty div just after the body tag with position:fixed rather than background-attachment:fixed which these devices doesn't support. All variations on the body element I've tried, like pseudo ::before is not working on these devices. An empty div solves this.

**Problem**
My script below works perfectly on my main page ('Home'/'Start'). But I also have other pages like 'Contact' and such, sharing the same 'global' head tag where the script lies, where it doesn't work (the div simply doesn't show up). I would expect this to add a div after each body element, regardless of which page is loaded... Also, I'm using `window.onload` as I can't manually add the script after the body tag. Each subpage body tag has its own id but why would that matter? ***What am I missing?***

```
window.onload = function FixedBg() {
  var body = document.body;
  var bgDiv = document.createElement('div');
  bgDiv.className = "fixedBackground";
  body.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', bgDiv);
}
```

I don't have access to manually add divs directly into the DOM which obviously would have been the approach otherwise, hence the JavaScript...

Comment: What exxactlx is the problem here? Is there an error on the console? is the div just not showing up?

Comment: maybe look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20665509/javascript-document-body-undefined-if-not-preceded-by-a-document-write

Comment: Does `insertAdjacentElement` not take a string of html rather than a dom node?

Comment: @katzenhut The div is just not showing up on other pages but the main/start page.

Comment: @CherryDT That does not work to get fixed background on these devices. I have too keep it outside the body tag altogether.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius If that were true, then I wouldn't see it work on my main/start page. Or can you elaborate what you think the problem is?

Comment: true enough - I guess it must treat the dom node as a string internally. Perhaps try binding the injection to the `DOMContentLoaded` event - see if that helps

Comment: document.body works on every page. The page itself has no knowlege where it deployed. It doesnt know the concept of subpages.

Comment: @TheFool My thought exactly. That's why I'm confused as to why it only works on the first page, but not my other pages. The script ends up in a global head tag (on all pages) and this is why I use window.onload (I can't put the script after the </body>

Comment: head is read before body, that may be the issue here. Try using domcontent loaded event for that or put the script at the bottom of your body.

Comment: @TheFool Again, in that case it wouldn't work on the first page but it does. I use window.onload to get around that

Comment: well you see there are some quirks no one understands. Why are you so much against simply using the more solid option?  using DOMContentLoaded  doesnt hurt you and its not more coding work execpt a couple more letter to type window.addEventListener.

Comment: @TheFool I'm not familiar with that syntax but I'll look it up

Comment: No-one should be using `window.onload` in this day-and-age. Or _any_ `onfoo` event-properties for that matter. **Always use `addEventListener`** - otherwise you'll end-up treading on some other library's toes.

Comment: could be that you first page is so small that its fast enough. Stuff like this is in nature of event driven asynchronous code.  `The DOMContentLoaded event will fire as soon as the DOM hierarchy has been fully constructed, the load event will do it when all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414750/difference-between-domcontentloaded-and-load-events

Answer (score 1):

As was suggested in the comments above by @ProfessorAbronsius and @TheFool, using `DOMContentLoaded` and an event listener did the trick! Thank you